# ¿como puedo quitar la cabecera y el pie de pagina de una sola pagina en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

muy buenos días/tardes/noches/ madrugadas: tengo un pequeño problema respecto al wordpress que me tiene intrigado por decir menos... verán, para quietar una parte de la pagina (normalmente) por ejemplo en about:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
voy al personalizador de paginas y voy al apartado de css adicional ya ahí puedo quitar el pie de pagina y la cabecera, hasta aqui todo bien...

pero, a la hora de ir a los temas de plantilla (theme templates) en la sección de pagelayer
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero quitar la cabecera y el pie de pagina en la plantilla 404... hago lo mismo ir al personalizador de paginas e intento quitar los elementos antes mencionados por medio del id pero no pasa nada, este es el código (o intento de código) que utilice para quitar la cabecera y el pie de pagina:

```css
.pagelayer-id-13  .pagelayer-header{
     display: none;
}
```

este código lo hago mediante el personalizador de adicional de css ya que tengo el plan mas bajo de hostgator así que no puedo hacer gran cosa (sin tener que sangrar mas dinero) alguna recomendación o solución, se los agradecería :)

Comment: ¿Es posible que haya una regla CSS con prioridad que anule esa? Cuando lo pones en el CSS y lo ves con el inspector del navegador ¿aparece la regla?

Comment: no que yo sepa pero deja lo checo y te digo si aparece alguna regla